# Convert hex string to number in mySQL

Tags: mysql, hex, varchar

I have a column that has the value '11B3' in it.  I want to write a SQL statement (in mySQL) that ands (&) that value with 0x1880 and returns the result.  I have been unable to treat the string column as a hex number.  I would be grateful for any assistance.

This does NOT work:

```
select szVersion,  hex(szVersion), concat("0x",szVersion)
```

This functions as desired (but doesn't pull from database:

```
select 0x11bx & 0x1880
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **CONV(szVersion,16,10)**. Below is a proof that it works as expected.

You wrote that you expect the same result as the result of the following statement:

```
SELECT 0x11B3 & 0x1880;
-> 4224
```

So we know that the desired result is the number 4224.

Now do the same thing with data from a table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_hex SELECT '11B3' AS szVersion;
SELECT CONV(szVersion,16,10) & 0x1880 FROM temp_hex;
-> 4224
```

The same result. Works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNHEX(str) to change Hex to Text and then concatenate them.

Comment: This seems to be getting closer.  When I [
    select unhex(mycolumn) from mytable ]
I get a blob using mySQL workbench.  I can click on the blob and I see that it holds 11 B3.  I try to and it with 0x1880, but I get 0.  How do I turn that blob to a number?

Comment: First on Workbench go to `Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor`, then mark the option Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string. Now you can cast 11B3 to char, just doing something like this: `SELECT CAST(UNHEX(mycolum) AS CHAR) AS NEW_COLUM FROM MY TABLE;`

Comment: I ended up using unhex to make a blob and then parsing it myself: `case 0x2200 & ascii(unhex(types.szVersion))*256+ ascii(substring(unhex(types.szVersion),2,1))`